# Ubuntu Xampp access localhost from other pc

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, localhost

I am trying to access my localhost from another computer using the local IP(192.168...)

The problem is that I get access forbidden.
I changed the httpd-xampp-conf and it looks like the following:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-st$ver-    status|server-info))">

    Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
            Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
       fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
      fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

But still no luck...Any ideas..??

Comment: Is it just phpmyadmin you can't access or do you have problem accessing every URL?

Comment: I have problem in every URL I try...

Comment: Post your entire httpd-xampp.conf httpd.conf. You might be missing the `Require all granted` directive in your `<Directory>` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever people on a linux system mention pre-packaged development environments I scream "ARRRRGHHHHHHH" at them and tell them that their computer is capable of running the same environment as production. Why are you running anything else?

```
sudo apt-get install php5 apache2 mysql
```

XAMPP is pretty terrible for dev environments. Set up an actual environment for your code; the experience is worth it.

---

Regardless, your issue is that XAMPP is bound to localhost, or `127.0.0.1`. Change `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` to `Listen 80`.

You could also try forwarding traffic, but that is a little bit overkill.

Also, your internal network (`192.168.0.0/16`) is only as secure as your router. If you feel comfortable allowing it, just bind XAMPP to your internal network address instead of `127.0.0.1` and allow everything globally. It'll save you a headache if you use different machines regularly.

Comment: In which file should I change the listen option..?

Comment: It *should* just be your `httpd-xampp` config

Comment: Hmm... Then you should probably try showing your config in full (since you're getting this on every URL, the issue is clearly not just that locationmatch block). Also, your example has been clipped (I'm assuming you edited that with `nano` and copy-pasted)

Comment: I just edited the first line...You were right..I copied it from nano...Which file you think i should include...??

Comment: @Santa If Apache was set to only listen to localhost the connection would never be fulfilled. Clearly he's getting a 403 forbidden error and therefore Apache already listens and establishes connections.